# Will a character work well with animation if it wasn't made with t-pose?

Tags: animation, rigging

So I modeled a low poly character for a friend and he will rig it and animate it, but I modeled it with the arms resting on the sides, not in a t-pose like it should be. Will it work anyway or will it become a problem when animation is done? I'm talking about simple walking animation, nothing complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not stick to a concept if it doesn't fit your needs. If your character's limbs can't even reach t-pose it's moot anyways. The main issue you might run into is axis alignment. It is a good idea to stick to 1 axis for bone directions, but it can't ever be possible in a complex character.
If your character's rest pose is different from the t-pose, use the one that's closest to what the char. does most of times. But note that IK constraints are easier to set up in t-pose.
I would suggest using none-t-pose and pose a few extremes, if there's no problem, there likely won't be one in the future.